# drag files here not available with wiki library?

Tags: file-upload, wiki, drag-and-drop

If I create a Document/Report Library in SharePoint, I can upload multiple or drag and drop files into it.

However, I really want to use a  Wiki Library, so I can have the functionality of creating quick web pages for references.

However, with the Wiki library, I can *"Add"* documents one at a time, but I don't have any way to *"Upload*" multiple documents or drag and drop documents, like I would with a Document or Report Library.

Can anyone explain why  or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the library with Windows Explorer and then copy/paste the documents from your local folder to the library.

Btw, you should not store the documents in the wiki library. The better approach would be to store them in separate document library, and make links to them in wiki pages as necessary.

Comment: Why shouldn't documents be stored in the wiki?

Comment: It would be better to separate the pages and the files that are linked to from those pages in order to keep the things "clean". That way it will be easier for you to keep the track of and maintain all the different assets. This is experience talking :)